# How to dissect an HTML page in Java, to pick out certain elements?

Tags: java, php, forms, http, post

For reasons that I don't want to go into for the purpose of this question, I have a Java class that posts an HTML form, and reads in the response.

A small snippet of the response I'm getting is :

```
<div class="main_box">

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4" class='results'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="title">Free Car ID Check Results</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='title' width='34%'>Vehicle Registration Number</td>
        <td width="43%">ABC123</td>
        <td width="23%" rowspan="4" valign="top"><p align="center"><img src="/media/FORD.jpg" alt="FORD" /></p>
        <p>      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  class='title'>Make</td>
        <td>FORD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='title'>Model</td>
        <td>ESCORT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='title'>Colour</td>
        <td>BLUE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

What would be the easiest, robust way of picking out the `make`, `model` and `colour` from this? This is only a small portion of the input stream I'm reading, and I can't guarantee that the HTML elements outside of this will remain the same, as in the web page may alter.

Thanks

Comment: "easy" and "robust" are in conflict.  :-)

Comment: hehe fair point, I'm open to either right now.. :P

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org). It allows you to easily read the document and select elements.

E.g.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class=main_box] td[class=title]");
for (Element anElement : elements) {
    // Real treatment here
    System.out.print(anElement.text());
    System.out.println(": "+anElement.nextElementSibling().text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" way, which I have used to grab data from web sites, is to carefully analyze their HTML, then just search for something distinctive like `">Make<"`, then search for the next `"<td>"`, then the next `"</td>"`, and grab what's in between.

This is obviously highly non-robust if they have any escape characters, if there is more than one instance of ">Make<", etc.  Or when they change their output in the future.

However, the "robust" methods with fancy XHTML parsers etc. typically *assume that the web site is serving back well formed HTML or XHTML*.  In my experience, *nobody serves back well formed HTML*.  :-(  Well, not many...  Arguably, my quick and dirty way is more robust than using a real parser.

p.s. - for those SO experts who will offer up real answers with real parsers, please describe how they handle poorly formed HTML, as I had real problems with that...

Comment: A robust HTML parser should (and does) not need well-formed HTML. XHTML is something different, of course.

Comment: @his  Which do you recommend?  I forget which HTML parser I tried, but apparently it wasn't robust enough.  I think I was also frustrated because I had tried a couple of XHTML parsers and they, obviously, failed miserably.  I'll take a look at JSoup, that was NOT the one I had tried.

Comment: I upvoted this answer. (X)HTML parsers seem to be overkill for what was asked here when a simple String.indexOf will work just fine, most likely in faster time and less memory.

Comment: Jsoup, if you don't need Javascript rendering, HtmlUnit if you do. For XHTML the XML API of your choice. Could you define what "robust" does mean for you? Obviously not the same as for me as manual text scraping and searching for "<td>" or such is the exact opposite of robust for me. Just think of someone adding a class for styling - no semantic change but completely breaks your approach.

Comment: @his I guess you have to ask "What's the liklihood of a breaking change of the simple scrape method?" vs "What added time/memory am I incurring for building a representation of the data and then walking through it instead of just scraping a string?"

Comment: "What is the cost of a breaking application" vs. "What is the cost of a few kb RAM and some CPU cycles". Sorry, that is a no brainer.

Comment: liklihood isn't equal to cost. With your solution, changing the td class from title to something else would break the application, so even with an HTML parser, you're using certain assumptions that, if changed, could break the application. So, what's the benefit of your approach over the simpler one?

Comment: My approach is simpler. Show your code, please. I present three to five lines that are semantic only, easily readable and break only under more severe conditions. String scraping can break with simple white space changes ("<td >"). When the other side changes it output so much that it breaks my code is much simpler to correct. At the cost of things that are next to worthless nowadays, especially in Java applications and this use case. A specific requirement was "robust". String scraping is contrary to that.

Comment: @his  I can't speak for Real Baumann, but, sometime over the next few days, I'll try replacing my hacky scraping code with JSoup.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, I promised @his that I would try JSoup and compare it to my more hacky "just search for >Make<" style code (which is in a small class I wrote called HTMLGrabber.)

First, I found JSoup easy to use, it handled at least one of the lousy HTML files I tested (there are three more to be tested).  The resulting code was similar in length to the HTMLGrabber code.  A bit longer, but not bad.  And HTMLGrabber isn't nearly as simple as I remember, as I've added some unescape/escape code, minor support for Attributes, etc...

**Any "scraping" approach is ultimately non-robust if the web site changes dramatically.**

The "advantages" of the HTMLGrabber style code is that you are searching based directly on the content.  In the car code example, you'd probably jump first to "Free Car ID Check Results", then look for ">Make<", then `"<td>"` and grab the text before the next 
`"</td>"`, yielding "FORD".  Then similar for ">Model<" and ">Color<".  Why is this possibly an "advantage"?  If the *structure* of the HTML changes, e.g. it's not in a table anymore, or more rows are added, this approach might still work.  i.e., it is "more robust" (but still far from perfect) in the face of structural changes in the HTML.

The advantage of the JSoup/"real parser" approach is that it handles goofy escape characters, plus, normally, (at least, how I would code it, YMMV) you would be following the structure of the HTML, at least in part, to find the things you want.  In the car example, you'd look for the div element with class "main_box", then find the table, then the rows etc...  This approach is more robust in the face of *content* changes.  For example, when your website gets bought out, and "Free Car ID Check Results" changes to "Facebook Car ID Check Results", this would still work.  (Note that nothing is perfect, if "main_box" changed to "primary_box" you'd be in trouble).

I have no idea if content or structural changes are more frequent in the random websites people are scraping.  Anybody have any stats or experiences there?

In summary, I found JSoup "easy enough" that I will use it most of the time in the future, since I suspect that it is, in general, more robust.  But, for many web sites, the "just grab it" approach may be superior.

ADDENDUM  For two of my web pages, the HTML was so jumbled that, even though Jsoup managed to parse it, using Jsoup to go down through the DOM proved so difficult that I stuck with the quick-and-dirty instead.

Answer (score -1):

try this
"http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_vb.html"
it is in microsoft language but it can be usefull if you'r willing to translate from one language to an other.
Good Luck!